# Mathematics should I learn for 2D and 3D game programming/development

Tags: game-design, graphics-programming

What mathematics should I learn to become game programer 2D and 3D. From the very basic for beginner until advance

Comment: Don't worry about studying all the "prerequisites" before starting game development. The particular math you need or don't need varies greatly from game to game, role to role. If you just focus on prototyping game features that interest you, they'll lead you to the math you need to accomplish that concrete goal, and you can learn as you go, testing your knowledge along the way with real playable applications.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually I just started learning programming language about 2 months ago and I have decided to become game developer/programming. Maybe it too soon for me to decide. I will see what I can find along the way. Thanks

Comment: Best of luck to you!